# Training data requirements for NLP models

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sampling

Are there general guidelines for how much data is required for natural language processing (NLP) classification models? I understand this may depend on the text quality, text length, how accurate the labels are, the event frequencies, the chosen algorithm, etc. Are there any general frameworks I can use to estimate how much data I would need? I'm going through an exercise of having data owners labeling their text data and i'd like to give them a recommendation for how much data they should label other than more is better.

Comment: It really depend on what you want to achieve. Generally, you should try to obtain as mush as data you can. Again as much is you can. After that, you start finding the best model for what amount of data you have.

Comment: Understood, but in this case I'm asking the business for data, so I need to give them some estimate for how much data I need. Even if I can give them some sort of tradeoff between between data and model performance that'd be sufficient.

Comment: It will vary on the difficulty of the problem, the complexity of the data, the quality of the labels and much more. Starting small, seeing if the performance is satisfactory and collecting more is a good appraoch. A great guide for labeling data for machine learning might help in the collection process: https://www.cloudfactory.com/data-labeling-guide